# Test one to many relationship working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

In my rails api I have multiple models with one to many relationships and I want a way to test that I didn't miss anything setting each of them up. What is the best way in Minitest to test if a one to many relationship is setup correctly? What I want to see is that one receipt can have many sales on it.

```
test 'multiple sales can have one receipt' do
 sale = Sale.new
 sale.receipt = 1234
 sale.save

 sale2 = Sale.new
 sale2.receipt = 1234
 sale2.save


 assert_equal sale.invoice_id, sale2.invoice_id, "receipts are not the same"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would test like this:

```
test 'one receipt can have multiple sales' do
  receipt = Receipt.last
  sale1 = receipt.sales.create
  sale2 = receipt.sales.create

  assert receipt.sales.size > 1, "receipt should have multiple sales"
  assert_equal sale1.receipt, sale2.receipt, "receipts are not the same"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The `shoulda-matchers` gem is my go-to gem for testing associations like this.  Saves the tedium of manually testing all the possible scenarios for the associations.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda

Just add the gem to your Gemfile and you can write your tests like...

```
class UserTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  should have_many(:posts)
end
```

Comment: Thanks Steve I'll look deeper into that. I may be restricted to not adding gem files to this project though. Might need a more manual approach but I do agree that that test looks lovely.